# Expected Value Probability

Tags: probability

(10 pts) Suppose that the distribution function of a random variable X is given by

$$F(t) =\begin{cases}
0 & : t <−1
\\
1/7 & : − 1≤t< 3
\\
3/7  & : 3≤t<4
\\
4/7  & : 4≤t<5
\\
1 & :   t≥5
\end{cases}$$

(a)  What is the range of X? Also give the probability mass function of X.

(b) What is the expected value of X?

For part B do i need to take into account t=0, 1 or 2 when calculating the expected value of X? Or do I ignore those values and just use -1,3,4,5? Any hits would be appreciated

Comment: Note that from the cdf we can conclude that $\Pr(X=-1)=1/7$, $\Pr(X=3)=2/7$, $\Pr(X=3)=1/7$ and $\Pr(X=5)=3/7$. The rest is routine.

Comment: Yes i Understand that, and also that Pr(X=4)=1/7, but do i need to calculate P(X=0)=1/2, for example, and factor that into my Expected Value equation?

Comment: @JacobRodgers, No. $P(X=0) = 0$  Can you see why?

Comment: The mean is (-1)(1/7)+(3)(2/7)+(4)(1/7)+(5)(3/7)$. Note I had a typo above, wanted $\Pr(X=4)=1/7$.

Answer (score 0):

> For part B do I need to take into account t=0, 1 or 2 when calculating the expected value of X? Or do I ignore those values and just use -1,3,4,5? Any hints would be appreciated

The second.  You need to use values in the support of $X$ --those values where it has a *non-zero* probability mass-- and the probability mass function you determined in part A.

$$E(X) = \sum_{t\in\{-1,3,4,5\}} t\;f_{_X}(t)$$

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters your pmf is

$
p_X(x) =Pr(X=x) =
\begin{cases}
1/7 & : x=-1
\\
2/7  & : x=3
\\
1/7  & : x=4
\\
3/7 & :   x=5
\end{cases}
$

To figure this out, recall that $F_X(x) = Pr(X<x) $ and you should be able to deduce my answer from every point that is less then or equal or greater than or equal.

By range I assume you mean support set, in this case it's $(-1,\infty)$ as x can take on any value greater than - 1 with probability more than 0.

Now given the pmf, part B should be really easy, just do:

$
E[X] = \sum_{x=-1}^5 x p_X(x) 
$

I got $E[X] = 12$